# activating python script with sudo gives out a syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, sudo

when I activate python script like this:

```
python main.py --train main 1
```

it runs fine without any syntax errors

but when I do this command:

```
sudo python main.py --train main 1
```

it gives me a syntax error:

`File "main.py", line 51 raise NameError(f"model must contain one of: {models}")`

`^`

how can I disable/ignore this syntax error (I don't want to change the string format)

Comment: F-strings (strings that start with `f"..."`) require Python version 3.6 or later.  What version of python are you using?

Comment: im using python 3.7 in virtual env using anaconda

Comment: and yes I did `sudo -E`

Comment: Just a shot in the dark as I don't know the contents of your script, but did you check your python version with and without sudo? Possibly your $PATH is different?
Can you please try:
`python --version` vs                                                                                                                                                      `sudo python --version`

Comment: When using sudo, you probably get to run a different (probably Python 2) version. Try `sudo python` to be sure.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille you right!
when using `sudo python` it says python version 2.x

Comment: @ThierryLathuille do you have any idea how to upgrade sudoer python?

Comment: I'm not sure that it will be easy to activate your virtual environment while sudoing. Do you really need to run this as root?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I need to give admin privilege to CUPTI and I cant find out how.

Comment: if you run it on Linux then you can use command `python3` or even `python3.7` to run script with correct version. `sudo python3.7 main.py --train main 1`